# how to write sql command for two commands in the report using the same parameter

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

i have created two commands to get datas to my crystal report. One command contains a parameter named as "fromDate". I need to use this parameter in command two. is there any way to use this parameter in command two

Comment: what is your report structure?

Comment: @Siva the report contains three paramaters as fromDate, toDate, acc_name. I need to write a command to get a sum of all records before fromdate. So i am trying to connect command one fromDate parameter to to command two like this. Bt it's not working.
Select SUM(CAST(debit as DECIMAL(9,2)))- SUM(CAST(credit as DECIMAL(9,2))) from 
sum_balance
where 
sum_date like {?fromDate}
and
sum_date < fromDate

Comment: instead of writing two commands you can use `Select Expert` to  write the conditions. have you tried that?

Comment: @Siva can we write a query in select expert to get the sum